# SQL How to group data into separate month columns

Tags: sql, analysis, orders

So I'm running this query to get the name of the customer, total amount ordered, and number of orders they've submitted. With this query, I get their entire history from March to July, what I want is the name, march amount total/# of orders, april amount total/# of orders, may amount total/# of orders, ..... etc.

```
SELECT customer_name,MONTH(created_on), SUM(amount), COUNT(order_id)
FROM customer_orders
WHERE created_on BETWEEN '2020-03-01' AND '2020-08-01' 
GROUP BY customer_name, MONTH(created_on)
```

Comment: Your query would appear to do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the values in separate *columns*, then use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT customer_name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(created_on) = 3 THEN amount END) as march_amount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(created_on) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as march_count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(created_on) = 4 THEN amount END) as april_amount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(created_on) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as april_count,
       . . .
FROM customer_orders
WHERE created_on >= '2020-03-01' AND
      created_on < '2020-08-01' 
GROUP BY customer_name;
```

Notice that I changed the date filter so it does not include 2020-08-01.

Comment: thank you! I added the rest of the SUM cases for the other months, but I am getting this error "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM rv_customer_orders WHERE created_on >= '2020-03-01' AND       created_on < ' at line 12"

Comment: @Neykof . . . You probably have a comma before the `on` clause.

Comment: I was doing some data validation, and I realized that it's missing some orders when I run the query. Is there any reason that would cause some orders to be skipped that you can think of?

Comment: @Neykof . . . It would skip orders that don't meet the condition on `created_on`.